# Regarding understanding a proof in Lang's Linear Algebra on Convex Sets

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

$\mathbf{Statement\ of\ the\ Problem:}$ I have been racking my brain trying to understand the proof of the following claim as laid out by Lang in his "Linear Algebra". The proof given hinges on the assumption that the summation over $s_i$ as defined on the page in the link I give is equal to 1. However, I don't see how he is justifying this assumption. From context, it looks like it may be a misprint as further along in the proof suggests that Lang meant that: $$s_i=\frac{t_i}{1-t_n}$$ rather than $$s_i=\frac{t_n}{1-t_n}$$. I have since been Googling hoping for a confirmation of a misprint, but can't seem to turn up anything. Can anyone act as a second opinion about whether or not the proof printed is correct, or at least point me in the right direction if I'm missing something. Taking that assumption to be correct, I see where it's going, but just can't seem to cross the bridge. [The link to the page where the proof is given below in my "Resources" section]

$\mathbf{Resource:}$
Link to page 79 of Serge Lang's Linear Algebra: https://books.google.com/books?id=0DUXym7QWfYC&pg=PA79&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: You are right, it's definitely a misprint. He meant $\frac{t_i}{1-t_n}$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : Thank you kindly I thought it may be given that further along in the proof, the sum at the end kind of hinges on $s_i$ being defined as dependent on i, but having only found nothing but praise for Lang's book when I tried to Google for a misprint, wanted to be sure. 

Also, should I leave this up? Given that this site is for sharing knowledge, and having found no reference to this misprint, I figure it would be a good idea to leave this sort of sign-post up if another traveler goes down this road. But, don't want anyone down voting because they think it's not a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You are completely right, this is a typo. Lang has the expression
$$
(1 - t_n)\left( \frac{t_1}{1 - t_n} P_1 + \dotsb + \frac{t_{n - 1}}{1 - t_n} P_{n - 1} \right) + t_n P_n
$$
and so he wants to define $\displaystyle s_i = \frac{t_i}{1 - t_n}$ for each $i \in \{ 1, \dotsc, n - 1\}$, not $\displaystyle \frac{t_n}{1 - t_n}$.

Note that it is only with the corrected version that we have $s_1 + \dotsb + s_{n - 1} = 1$, as Lang notes in the very next line.